# Chain multiple expressions in AngularJS ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to chain two different expressions into an `ng-class`, one of them have a filter applied to it, something like:

```
<body ng-class="controller | camel2hyphens" ng-class="{overflow: isOverflow}">
```

But Angular only uses one of the them (which makes sense).

I've tried using an array of expression this way:

```
<body ng-class="[(controller | camel2hyphens), {overflow: isOverflow}]">
```

But the CSS class that is set is:

```
class="login-controller [object Object]"
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with `ng-class` (without writing a method in the Controller with the logic).

Thanks!

Comment: does `ng-class="{overflow: isOverflow} {{controller | camel2hyphens}}"` work?

Comment: Or something like `class='{{controller|camel2hyphens}}'` for the first expression

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, but it does not work, it prints the `controller` variable into the `ng-class` directly: `<body ng-class="{overflow: isOverflow} login-controller" class="overflow"></div>`

Comment: @Chandermani that did it, thanks! but I was looking for a way to chain both expressions in the same `ng-class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `class` in combination with `ng-class`

```
<body class="{{controller | camel2hyphens}}" ng-class="{overflow: isOverflow}">
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it, although, I was looking for a way of having a single expression (probably with two sub expressions) inside the `ng-class`. I was playing with it a few days ago, and got something working, unfortunately I lost that code :(

Comment: What I ended doing was: `ng-class="[(controller | camel2hyphens), isOverflow ? 'overflow' : '']"`, not sure if this has any advantages over your answer thought. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the way you tried to do it is only supported with [Angular >=1.4](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

For [Angular 1.2](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and [1.3](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

> If the expression evaluates to an array, each element of the array should be a string that is one or more space-delimited class names.

This way, your own suggestion was the best because all code stays inside of ng-class.

```
ng-class="[(controller | camel2hyphens), isOverflow ? 'overflow' : '']
```